# Django Rest Partial Update

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am working on finding the critical path for a set of tasks. For that I added a `critical` boolean field in the task model which is set to `False` by default. Once this logic is run, I want to update this field as `True` for critical tasks. Can someone help?
Also, once marked critical, I want to update the status (Textfield) for all the critical tasks in a separate model. Here are my files:

models.py:

```
class Task_category(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job,related_name='Job',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    assigner = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='assigner', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='assignee', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit,related_name='UnitName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    equipment = models.ForeignKey(Equipment,related_name='EquipmentName',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    share_with = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)
    end_date =  models.DateField()
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True,blank=True)   
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(TaskStatus, related_name='Status',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    predecessor = models.ManyToManyField("self",blank=True)
    critical = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=400,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return(self.name)
```

views.py:

```
class GanffView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ["get"]
    task_list = Task_category.objects.all()
    subtask_list = Subtask_category.objects.all()
    tasks, critical = cpmlogic(task_list)
```

The cpmlogic returns a dictionary 'tasks' which has a 'isCritical' key that is True for critical tasks. I want to use that to update the `critical` field in the tasks so that it can be used later on

Answer (score 0):

you can override the perform_update method for ModelViewSet

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    # some condition
    serializer.save(critical=True)
```

Comment: Ok got it. But what if I want to manually enter text and then update?

Comment: you can provide any field on .save

Comment: can you please elaborate how do I write the condition. Do i have to iterate over all tasks using for loop?

Comment: Just add any condition on after the serializer.save(), its either you update or delete